# Complete Normed Space => Uncountable Hamel basis not by Baire

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

I need to show that a complete normed space X has no countable Hamel basis.

One possibility is to with Baire's theorem.

I, however, try to give an explicit sequence, namely:

For a contradition, let $\mathcal{B} = \{b_i, i\in\mathbb N \}$ the countable Hamelbasis of X.

W.l.o.g. $B_i\ne 0$ for all $i$.

Define: $x_n=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i^2} \frac{b_i}{\|b_i\|}$. Obviously $(x_n)_n$ is Cauchy.

But then it has a limit $x=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{i^2} \frac{b_i}{\|b_i\|}$, which has no finite decomposition $x=\sum_{k=1}^M \lambda_k \frac{b_{i_k}}{\|b_{i_k}\|}$ because the base elements are linearly independed.

Is that also a correct proof?

Thanks.

Comment: I believe the last step requires more justification. Obviously monomials on $[0,1]$ and $e^x$ are linearly independent (hence basis $B$ of some space), partial sums of of Taylor expansion of exponential function (plus, say, $e^x$ with coefficient $0$) form a sequence convergent to an element of this space, yet this element can be expressed in the basis $B$.

Comment: There's a hole in that argument, I think. You seem to be arguing that no *finite* sum of basis vectors can yield $x$, because $x$ is defined as an *infinite* sum of such vectors. But how do you know that? Linear independence *only* requires finite linear combinations to be unique, infinite linear combinations can pretty much behave however they want, I'd say.

Comment: @ Marcin:
Thanks for your example, but I have coefficients not equal to 0 on every element of the base.

Comment: You wrote *I need to show that a complete normed space X has no uncountable Hamel basis*. I'm pretty sure you want to say "has no countable Hamel basis".

Comment: Let $X=\ell^2$, let $b_1 = \left(\frac{1}{2^2}, \frac{1}{3^2},\frac{1}{4^2},\frac{1}{5^2},\dotsc\right)$ and $b_i = e_{i-1}$ for $i \geqslant 2$, where $e_k$ is the $k$-th "standard unit vector". Then $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{i^2}\frac{b_i}{\lVert b_i\rVert}$$ is a multiple of $b_1$.